# Почему PHP видит не все поля объекта?

Tags: php, redbeanphp

Хочу получить значения полей `descriptionID` и `paragraphID`, но код совсем их не видит. При этом поля `text` и `id` видит прекрасно. Не понимаю, что не так делаю. Помогите осознать ошибку, пожалуйста!

P.S. используется RedBeanPHP; в `$texts` возвращается массив объектов; `$text` - объект с полями, указанными на скриншоте 1

```
<?php 
$texts = R::find(/* мой запрос (правильный) */);
$paragraphID = 2;
foreach($texts as $text){
    echo($paragraphID." - paragraphID<br>");
    echo($text->id." / ".$text['id']."<br>");
    echo($text->descriptionID." / ".$text['descriptionID']."<br>");
    echo($text->paragraphID." / ".$text['paragraphID']."<br>");
    echo($text['text']." / ".$text->text);
    $paragraphID++;
} ?>
```

Скриншот 1: (бд в phpMyAdmin)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скриншот 2: (что выводится в браузере)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: сверхсекретный sql-запрос напиши

Comment: @Jean-Claude, текст кода я прикрепил также

Comment: @Jean-Claude, я его замазал, так как суть вовсе не в нем

Comment: Скорее всего запрос неправильный и суть в нём.

Comment: @ЕгорБанин, но поля id и text как он видит, если запрос неправильный?

Comment: @KirillPeace например если там `select id, text from texts...`

Comment: ну так мы тебе и не поможем, это надо в НАСА писать по поводу сверхсекретного запроса.

Comment: Не надо))
SQL запрос: `$texts = R::find('mytable', 'descriptionID = ?', [$id]);`, где `$id` ранее был определен

Comment: @KirillPeace сделайте `var_dump($text);` Что там вообще получилось? Возможно  опечатки в названиях столбцов или Redbean не умеет camelCase в названиях полей (сейчас гляну).

Comment: @ЕгорБанин
object(RedBeanPHP\OODBBean)#18 (10) { ["properties":protected]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["descriptionID"]=> string(1) "1" ["paragraphID"]=> string(1) "2" ["text"]=> string(15) "Размеры:" } ["__info":protected]=> array(7) { ["type"]=> string(16) "description_text" ["sys.id"]=> string(2) "id" ["sys.orig"]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["descriptionID"]=> string(1) "1" ["paragraphID"]=> string(1) "2" ["text"]=> string(15) "Размеры:" } 
Есть и дальше, но превышает длину комментария

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Методом проб и ошибок я нашел верный и легкий способ избежать данной проблемы.
Всё решается заменой функции `find` на `getAll`:
``` $texts = R::getAll("SELECT * FROM ``mytable`` WHERE ``descriptionID`` = '$id'"); ```

Таким образом, в бд можно оставить `descriptionID` и `paragraphID` в данном виде.
Обращение же к полям объекта `$text` производится следующим образом: `$text['text']` , `$text['descriptionID']` , `$text['paragraphID']` и т.д.

Comment: Обратите внимание, что у вас тут потенциальная [SQL-инъекция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0): `"SELECT ... '$id'"`.

Answer (score 2):

RedBeanPHP довольно странный инструмент для работы с бд, поэтому он делает [так](https://github.com/gabordemooij/redbean/blob/master/RedBeanPHP/OODBBean.php#L1038)

```
if ( !ctype_lower( $property ) ) { // если camelCase (например paragraphID)
    $property = $this->beau( $property ); // поменять на snake_case (paragraph_id)
    ...
}

// искать поле (paragraph_id)
```

RedBean думает что поля в вашей бд названы в snake_case (это дурацкая практика, которая до сих пор широко распространена), а обращаться вы будете к ним в camelCase (у вас же ООП и всё такое). И он заботливо преобразует имена в snake_case. Довольно мило с его стороны :-)

Единственный способ побороть это -- задать алиас в snake_case для этих полей.

Comment: Кстати, проблемы возникнут и при попытке записать в эти поля :-) @Kirill Peace вам точно нужен этот RedBean? Может быть просто бахнуть на PDO?

Comment: Поменял descriptionID -> description_id в бд: все заработало так, как надо. Спасибо большое за помощь, я бы не догадался никогда до такого))
Но вот странность какая: напишу я `$text->paragraph_id` или `$text->paragraphID`, в любом случае находит такое поле и выдает правильное значение. Но ведь это же чистый php без вмешательства RedBean, тогда почему здесь тоже идет (как я понял) преобразование из camelCase в snake_case?

Comment: @KirillPeace какой чистый php, $text - это объект, созданный рэдбином.